# How can I setup the Trac Repository authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, trac

I'm controlling the user authentication to the repository through apache.

So my dav_svn.conf is the following:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn_access_control
```

And the svn_access_control is the following:

```
[groups]
team = jjtt
admin = robu

[/]
@team = rw


[/wlp]
@team = rw
@admin = rw


[/wesys]
@team = rw
```

I setup the trac login as well

```
   <LocationMatch "/trac/[^/]+/login">
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Trac"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
      Require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>
```

But I want to control the access to the repository browsing as well. In trac I can control a few things, but not the repository access. How can I add to the trac the something like `AuthzSVNAccessFile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Trac Fine Grained Permissions](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions).